# Comparing jsx elements with their unique id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array which stores jsx elements. Before pushing a new element. I want to make a check if the array contains an element with the same unique id or not.

Here is an example jsx element;

```
<Form.Control id = "formControl1"  placeholder = {this.state.placeholder} />
```

When I push this element to my array, I want to check whether there is an element with the same unique id `formControl1` or not. How would I do that in the most elegant way? I would convert the jsx to json with the help of some plugins or I could convert it to string and make my comparision with a for loop, but I am looking for the **most elegant** way.

Thanks.

Comment: one way is to make an object instead of an array with keys equal to ids and value equals to stringified jsx elements. While adding new element you can just look for the key in the object, if it's not present then add it. Whenever you require jsx array, You can just use Object.values.

Comment: @ArpitKapadia, looks valid but how would I extract the id value from jsx element? Are there an easy way to do this so?

Comment: If your jsx element is stored in a variable like `const element = <From.control id='formControl1' />`, then try using `element.props.id`.

Comment: @ArpitKapadia, it is coming to a function as a parameter. Will that work?

Comment: There's only one way to find out... Try it.

Comment: I can try it but another readers of this question may need this information in future.

Comment: It will work if the argument is a jsx element.

Comment: Is the jsx already rendered on the screen before you push the element? Or are using the check to determine whether you want to create that element?